# Mvn release a pom that contains a parent

Tags: maven, build, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to create a release for a repo. The problem I'm having is that when I run

```
mvn release:prepare -DdryRun= true
```

I am trying to run it on a pom.xml that has a parent.

This is the pom.xml that I am trying to release.

```
...
<parent>
<groupId>com..ehr</groupId>
<artifactId>ehr-common</artifactId>
<version>0.5.0.26</version>
<relativePath> ../../EhrPom/main/pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
...
```

When I run the mvn release:prepare -DdryRun= true. I receive this error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com//ehr//0.5.0.26/ehr-
-0.5.0.26.pom
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR]   The project com..ehr:emergency-login-webapp:2.0.7.0-SNAPSHOT   
(/Users/computer1/Documents/computer1_MacBook/depot//-  
webapp/main/pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact  in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath'
points at wrong local POM @ line 8, column 11 -> [Help 2] 
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the 
following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2]  
http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/UnresolvableModelException
```

Do I need to release the parent pom before to make this work? Does this have anything to due with the fact that its trying to download from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/ and not my repo? Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must deploy the parent POM as well, because others need it when they depend on your artifact. The parent `pom.xml` may contain further dependencies, properties and so on. Therefore you will need to deploy it to your (remote) repository.

It might be easier for you to create a top-level `pom.xml` which contains the parent and artifacts as modules. Maven takes care of the right order, if you start the release process in this project, i.e. it will automatically release/deploy your parent POM before your artifacts. Or if your parent POM is your root POM at the same time, just start the release process there and its modules should be automatically released too.

**References:**

- [Multi module projects](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html)

Answer (score 0):

Made a dumb mistake, wasn't setting up for the correct repository :/